# How to handle Ajax browser compatibility without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have js functions as follows

```
//getting element by id
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

//ajax request handling

function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
       return true; 
    }
}
```

How to handle browser compatibility without jQuery?

Comment: What compatibility problems are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different options if you Google it, but here is one I found at:
https://github.com/ilinsky/xmlhttprequest

The basic idea is what I think you will find helpful, with how they are looking to decide which class to use.

```
var oXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;

// Define on browser type
var bGecko  = !!window.controllers;
var bIE     = !!window.document.namespaces;
var bIE7    = bIE && window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 7.0/);

// Enables "XMLHttpRequest()" call next to "new XMLHttpRequest()"
function fXMLHttpRequest() {
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest || bIE7) {
        this._object = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } // only use initial XHR object internally if current reference to XHR is our normalized replacement 
    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest.isNormalizedObject) {
        this._object = new oXMLHttpRequest();
    } // otherwise use whatever is currently referenced by XMLHttpRequest
    else {
        this._object = new window.XMLHttpRequest();     
    }
```

Comment: Actually it worth looking at. I apreciate.